# What is the method of going into the Sharan of Krishna?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

Bhagwan Krishna in [Bhagwad Gita (18:66)](https://bhagavadgita.io/chapter/18/verse/66) says to go into his Sharan ?

I want to know what is the method for it ?